# Importing a module from a parent package

Tags: python, import, path, parent

I have this directory structure

```
src
|
|\Lib
| |__init__.py
| |utils.py
|  \Scripts
|   |__init__.py
|   |myscript.py
|__init__.py
```

and I need to import `utils.py` in `myscript.py` but `from ..utils import function` is giving me

```
ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package
```

so my attempt is to add the parent package to the path by doing

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
sys.path.append(str(Path(__file__).resolve().parents[1]))
```

inside the innermost `__init__.py` (under the `Scripts` folder) without any success.

What am I missing here?

Comment: how are you running the code? can you show how you run myscript.py? the package structure looks good to me it seems like you are using interactive python in some way?

Comment: I'm running `myscript.py` from the `Lib` folder

Comment: If you run it from the lib folder then it cannot work. Your root package is `src`

Comment: so what does it mean?

Comment: It's not clear what are you trying to do. Are you trying to do something like in the terminal `../src/Lib> python myscript.py`

Comment: I fixed my question because I was missing a folder

Comment: As I said I asked clarification on what you are trying to do. My guess is that you are trying to run the python module as a script from the terminal as I explained in the above comment. This won't work because relative imports don't work is the module is invoked as a script. See here for more detailed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time. The solution is to move the script outside the package.

Comment: I need to run a function defined in `utils.py` from `myscript.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion to have a good understanding of how to deal with this kind of problem is to read this post:
[Relative imports for the billionth time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time)

One solution to your problem could be the following:

1. Have this folder structure

```
src
|
|\Lib
| |__init__.py
| |utils.py
|  
|\Scripts
| |myscript.py
```

2. Keep this in your `myscript.py`

```
import sys
from pathlib import Path
sys.path.append(str(Path(__file__).resolve().parents[1]))
```

and change `from ..utils import function` to `from Lib.utils import function`

This is one way to solve it.

Comment: The solution 2 gives me `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Lib.utils'`

Comment: be sure is `from Lib.utils import function` with capital L and that the this line is put after `sys.path.append(str(Path(__file__).resolve().parents[1]))`

Comment: I see. It works for me so I am pretty sure you are doing something different. Lib and Scripts are at the same level under src. can you write how you execute the script? If that doesn't work you maybe someone else can help Cheers

Comment: `Lib` and `Scripts` are not at the same level, `Scripts` is contained inside `Lib`, I cannot change the directory structure. Sorry, I misunderstood your solution.

Comment: In this case there is no solution to your problem.

Comment: may I ask you why

Comment: as I explained I suggested to read this post where it's explained in detail: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132789/relative-imports-for-the-billionth-time. The solution proposed there is the same one I proposed. If you read that post you'll understand. You need to change the folder structure in order to make it work. That's the way python import system works

Comment: Running using `python -m src.Lib.Scripts.myscript` will not throw any error on `from ..utils import function`, so what's the point of using the `sys.path.append(str(Path(__file__).resolve().parents[1]))` trick?